# Create a query with OR & And condition in elasticsearch Python

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I am trying to convert this sql query to the DSL query to query in Python

```
select * from dean_acc_p_alm_asset
where (substring(cast(sys_updated_on as varchar),1,10) >= '2021-11-01' and substring(cast(sys_updated_on as varchar),1,10) < '2021-11-02')
or (substring(cast(u_state_date as varchar),1,10) >= '2021-11-01' and substring(cast(u_state_date as varchar),1,10) < '2021-11-02')
```

I tried multiple ways to do that but could not get success. One of the examples I tried is

```
alm_asset_result = es.search(index=alm_asset_index,size = 10000,body={"query": {"bool": {"should": [{"range" : {"sys_updated_on" : {"gte" : tempStart, "lte": tempEnd}}},{"range" : {"u_state_date" : {"gte" : tempStart, "lte": tempEnd}}}]}}})
```

Can you please correct where I am doing mistakes? Thank you

Comment: do you want only count for document based on condition right  ?

Comment: No, I am reading this into the dataframe.

alm_asset_result_df = Select.from_dict(alm_asset_result).to_pandas()

Comment: but your SQL query `select count(*)` looks like it will return only count.

Comment: yes. That's a secondary part, Main part is the where condition which I want to write in the  DSL query format in the body to query the data.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass by a [filter context](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-filter-context.html#filter-context), instead of query context, to retrieve a more correct answer.

They have different purposes.
I redirect you to a good article: [Elasticsearch Differences Between Queries and Filters](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/elasticsearch-differences-between-queries-and-filters/)

Try:

```py
alm_asset_result = es.search(index=alm_asset_index,size = 10000,body={
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "filter": [
                { 
                    "bool": {
                        "should": [
                            {
                                "range": {
                                    "sys_updated_on": {
                                        "gte": tempStart,
                                        "lte": tempEnd
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "range": {
                                    "u_state_date": {
                                        "gte": tempStart,
                                        "lte": tempEnd
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
})
```